# How to init DataTable in Vue3 application after table render

Tags: vue.js, datatables, render, vuejs3

I have a Vue3 component which make an ajax request to server which sends array with articles back. Then I need to render the html table according the filled model via v-for and then init DataTable via DataTable() call on this rendered table. But it seems the problem is that DataTable() call runs before html table is rendered so the table is empty.

The ajax code looks like:

```
getArticles() 
{
    axios.get( apiRoutes.ARTICLES_URL )            
        .then((response) => {
            let data = response.data.articles;

            // Fill the model
            this.articles = data;

            // Init DataTable
            $('#dataTable').DataTable({ ... });

            //setTimeout(this.setDataTable, 3000);  // This works but want to avoid it.
        })
},
```

The template code

```
<template>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table :id="id" class="table table-bordered nowrap" width="100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Created</th>
                    <th>Visible</th>
                    <th>User</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">
                    <td>{{article.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.title}}</td>
                    <td data-order='{{article.created_at}}'>{{getCreatedAt(article.created_at)}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.visible}}</td>
                    <td>{{article.user.name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggleVisibility(article.id)">{{article.visible === 1 ? 'hide' : 'show'}}</a>
                        <a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteArticle(article.id)" class="text-danger">delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The question is how to properly wait for the render is done? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand it I need to use [$nextTick()](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/instance-methods.html#nexttick) which will wait while the DOM render is done.

Comment: Did you manage it? Do you maybe know the answer to my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71250563/vue-3-datatables-net-data-table-does-not-update-on-filtering It is somewhat related :)

Comment: Did you try NextTick()?

Comment: Here is my working example https://github.com/camohub/tatrytec-vue-admin/blob/master/src/components/articles/ArticlesDataTable.vue